# Complete Asynchronous call on each loop and go next Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am just facing a situation in my current work. I want to know the best pattern to work in this scenario

My code is something like this

```
for(var i =0 ;i < collection.length; i++){
  asynCall( collection[i],function(){....})//doing a asynchronous call
}
```

I just want to know the best patten to do the functionality such as

I want to complete each asynchronous call at a time and take the next record,

- for i = 0 do the asynchronous function, complete it, go to next
- for i = 1 do the asynchronous function ,complete it, go to next

and so on, at each iteration **'i'**  I want to complete the asynchronous call and after completing it only take the next record

Is there any method to do the functionality in this way. Or is there any other way to do it, is there any modules in npm which may help me

Please guide me with the best solutions

Comment: Try https://github.com/baryon/named-promise-task

Answer (score 2):

Using [async.js eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) :

```
async.eachSeries(collection, function(collectionItem, callback) {
    asynCall(collectionItem, callback);
}, function(err){
    //Handle errors here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest approach would be to use a library that manages async control flow, like [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async).

You could use `async.series` to call async functions one by one.

```
async.series([
  function (callback) {
    asynCall(collection[0], callback);
  },
  function (callback) {
    asynCall(collection[1], callback);
  },
  ...
]);
```

Or, if You prefer to keep things simple, you could use plain old recursion.

```
var i = 0;
(function loop() {
  asynCall(collection[i], function () {
    if (++i < collection.length) loop();
  });
}());
```

If you really want to sequentially call async functions inside the loop, it is also possible with `async/await`.

```
function wrapInPromise(x) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    asynCall(x, resolve);
  });
}

var collection = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

async function doAsyncStuff() {
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i += 1) {
    await (wrapInPromise(collection[i]));
  }
}

doAsyncStuff();
```

Though, you need [some effort](http://masnun.com/2015/11/11/using-es7-asyncawait-today-with-babel.html) to make this actually work.

Comment: okay,, thanks man...., But just for curiosity i want to know, is there any way that i can work async series method inside a for loop